# Add user in database?

Tags: sql-server, database, addition

I have a user which can login in sql server. Now i need to add user in database, however i am not sure if that user already exists in database or not.
So i need script, which checks if the user exists in database or not, and if doesn't it should add that user in that database.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this worked:

IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('login') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [username] FOR LOGIN [login]
END

^ this only works if the username in database is same as login.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a duplicate user, so you could just try and create it and handle the error if it's already there.

Comment: @Paul Creasey, The OP doesn't want to have duplicate users hence the post. Your answer is merely repeating what the OP said.

Comment: @Helen, it is not possible to insert a duplicate user, sys.database_principals.name has a unique constraint on it. I'm simply offering an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the user catalog view, [`sys.database_principals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx):

```
select * from [dbname].sys.database_principals 
where name = 'loginname';
```

To be 100% accurate you need to check by user's [SID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179889.aspx), not by name:

```
select * from [dbname].sys.database_principals 
where sid = SUSER_SID('loginame');
```

Note that users may have access already through group and role membership, but that is a separate topic.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `SELECT COUNT(*)`, and see whether you get a 0 or a 1.